# Please help me find the domain of a function

Tags: functions

I need to find the domain of the function:

$$L(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

$f(x)=\frac 1x$ and $g(x)=\frac 1{1-x}$

I think that $L(x)=\frac{\frac 1 x}{\frac 1{1-x}}=\frac {x-1}{x}$

Is the domain of $L(x)$ given by $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ or  by $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0,1\}?$

Comment: IMO, $D(L(x))=D(f(x)) \cap D(g(x)) \cap g(x)\neq0$, so it's the second option that you have suggested... But it could be the first, if you simplify $L(x)$ to $\frac{x-1}{x}$, as you noted. In any case, this question does **not** deserve a down-vote!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I think the down-votes were given before I edited the question. The OP had asked a good question (I only made it readable).

Comment: @tomi: I think that the down-votes here are a direct consequence of the [bandwagon effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect), as often happens on this website (for both down-votes and up-votes).

Comment: @barakmanos I agree. It's too easy to down-vote a novice (as we can see by their rating) rather than edit or advise on how to improve layout. I think it is a good question.

Comment: @tomi: Yes, and in addition to the fact that it's a good (non-trivial) question, the OP has also shared his/her thoughts of the possible answers.

Comment: Since f(0) and g(1) are not defined, f(x)/g(x) is not defined when x=0 or x=1. The equation L(x)=x/(x-1) is invalid when x=0 or x=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$D_{\frac fg}=(D_f\cap D_g)-\left\{x\in D_g\,\Big{|}\,g(x)=0\right\}=(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})\cap(\mathbb{R}-\{1\})-\{\}=\mathbb{R}-\{0,1\}$$